# I'm getting a java.lang.classnotfoundexception: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, android, jdbc

How come I get this error?
Check the picture:
[image]

I used the same jar on normal java projects(not android ones) and it used to work.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` because your jar file is not available at runtime. In order for it to be available at runtime you'll have to check the checkboxes on your jar file in your java build path like so:
[image]