# Android Library project in Eclipse: RunTimeException ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

The following code is from an Android app which has a library, a trial and a full app. In the project properties, the library is set as library and in trial/full the library is referenced. 
However, I seem to have missed something in naming the packages or the android:name(s):

If I try to run the full app, the app stops on the mobile with the following message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(28658): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{at.prm.privatecalls/at.prm.privatecalls.library.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "at.prm.privatecalls.library.SettingsActivity" on path: /data/app/at.prm.privatecalls-1.apk
```

**Manifest of lib:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="at.prm.privatecalls.library"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="@string/versionname" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    ...
</application>
```

**Manifest of app:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="at.prm.privatecalls"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="@string/versionname" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity 
        android:name="at.prm.privatecalls.library.SettingsActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964392/im-getting-a-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver/13964418#13964418, if this does not work then it could be an issue with the apk. Try deleting the bin folder and compile again.

Comment: Thanks for the link! In the Java Build Path, tab Libraries, I have Android 4.2 and Android Dependencies, and if I expand dependencies the privatcalls.lib.jar is listed with correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I startet with a fresh app, created library and two projects for full and trial and then copied over the code. Works, however, I do not know the reason for the error.