# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker

Tags: android, google-drive-api, noclassdeffounderror

Ok, I have been losing a lot of sleep over this, I can not seem to find what the issue is.

I am trying to integrate google drive with a big application I am working on with a team. .

Here is what logcat spits out:

```
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(GoogleAccountCredential.java:171)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at graef.mobile.activities.DriveHandler.onCreate(DriveHandler.java:36)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
02-09 10:13:40.979: E/AndroidRuntime(9768):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have all the libraries I need, I have also gotten a few Multiple dex errors. so I have nothing in my libs folder because I found that as a solution to that problem because of double jars in /libs and /bin/dexedLibs

Any help would much be appreciated

Let me know what other information I need to provide.

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964392/im-getting-a-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver/13964418#13964418)

Comment: No dice, I had already done that with Drive API

Comment: NO FILES IN LIBS! I think this is the culprit. What's your ADT level? Is it above 17?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I needed to make sure I had google play service imported and checked in order and export

Comment: Thanks, I was using the play services and forgot to check the box on google-play-services.jar, crap...

Answer (score 2):

I also had same problem, until I add:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker;
```

in my `activity.java` file. Hope it works for your problem too.

Comment: Well code wouldn't compile if you didn't do the **import** anyway.