# hellodropbox error

Tags: android, mobile, dropbox

I'm trying to develop an Android app that uses Dropbox's API.

I've done exactly how it's shown in [Dropbox's tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/tutorial/android) but when I start the application the application crashes and LogCat in Eclipse returns me these errors:

```
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at com.dropbox.sample.hellodropbox.HelloDropboxActivity.onCreate(HelloDropboxActivity.java:35)
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-26 01:08:13.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1210): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas on what's happening?

Comment: take a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964392/im-getting-a-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver/13964418#13964418

Comment: make sure the jar is in a folder called libs/ not lib/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the jar is correctly linked to the project. To do this, put it in the libs folder in your project's root and then:

1) Right click your project in eclipse
2) Select *Build Path* > *Configure Build Path*...
3) Ensure the Libraries tab is selected and click the *Add JARs...* button.
4) Navigate to your libs subfolder in your project and select the library to add.
5) Select *OK* button, and the select the *OK* again until you are back in your main eclipse perspective. The library should now be correctly linked to your project.
6) Lastly, do a clean on the project and things should build correctly.