# NoClassDefFoundError when using Parse.com to login to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I am currently using parse.com as a backend solution for my Android app. I am trying to use Facebook to authenticate users and I'm currently experiencing the errors below. I have tried to add both JARS (Parse and Facebook) to my project. I have also cleaned my project several times but I still get the errors below :

Error Log :

```
03-03 15:01:18.273: E/dalvikvm(7423): Could not find class 'com.facebook.SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy', referenced from method com.parse.auth.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.authenticate
03-03 15:01:18.273: W/dalvikvm(7423): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1011 (Lcom/facebook/SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy;) in Lcom/parse/auth/FacebookAuthenticationProvider;
03-03 15:01:18.277: D/dalvikvm(7423): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0033
03-03 15:01:18.277: E/dalvikvm(7423): Could not find class 'com.facebook.SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy', referenced from method com.parse.auth.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.restoreAuthentication
03-03 15:01:18.277: W/dalvikvm(7423): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1011 (Lcom/facebook/SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy;) in Lcom/parse/auth/FacebookAuthenticationProvider;
03-03 15:01:18.277: D/dalvikvm(7423): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x003b
03-03 15:01:18.277: D/dalvikvm(7423): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x21d7 at 0x35 in Lcom/parse/auth/FacebookAuthenticationProvider;.authenticate
03-03 15:01:18.281: D/dalvikvm(7423): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x21d7 at 0x3f in Lcom/parse/auth/FacebookAuthenticationProvider;.restoreAuthentication
03-03 15:01:18.324: D/AndroidRuntime(7423): Shutting down VM
03-03 15:01:18.328: W/dalvikvm(7423): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dc6300)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at com.parse.auth.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at com.parse.ParseUser.authenticateAsync(ParseUser.java:1096)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at com.parse.ParseUser.logInWithAsync(ParseUser.java:1113)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at com.parse.ParseUser.logInWithAsync(ParseUser.java:938)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(ParseFacebookUtils.java:338)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(ParseFacebookUtils.java:363)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at com.example.chartviewer.FbLoginActivity.onCreate(FbLoginActivity.java:44)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-03 15:01:18.371: E/AndroidRuntime(7423):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

New Error log after adding Jars:

```
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategy
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at com.parse.auth.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at com.parse.ParseUser.authenticateAsync(ParseUser.java:1096)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at com.parse.ParseUser.logInWithAsync(ParseUser.java:1113)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at com.parse.ParseUser.logInWithAsync(ParseUser.java:938)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(ParseFacebookUtils.java:338)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(ParseFacebookUtils.java:363)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at com.example.chartviewer.FbLoginActivity.onCreate(FbLoginActivity.java:44)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-03 15:15:09.472: E/AndroidRuntime(8203):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are the jars in the `/libs` folder?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964392/im-getting-a-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver/13964418#13964418). Also the jar should be in the libs folder, like Raghav already mentioned :)

Comment: @RaghavSood the Parse jar and the facebook android support jar are both in the libs folder, i still get the same errors.

Comment: @RaghavSood i have added the new error log after adding jars.

Comment: @RaghavSood i contacted Parse, and it might be a problem with the Facebook SDK i'm using thanks though.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you checked the checkbox in `Java Build Path` -> `Order and Export`-tab.

[image]
(Image from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964392/im-getting-a-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver/13964418#13964418))

Answer (score 0):

I Got solution by changing my minSdkVersion(11 to 8)