# App crashes saying that a library is not included, even though it is

Tags: android, event-bus

My Android app seemed to have been working fine till i did a git reset on it. Now it keep crashing and says that a library I am using is not present.

This is the crash log I get

```
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de.greenrobot.event.EventBus$3
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.postToSubscription(EventBus.java:413)
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.postSingleEvent(EventBus.java:399)
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at de.greenrobot.event.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:326)
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at com.cobboc.eashmartdemo.Session$5.onError(Session.java:362)
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at com.cobboc.eashmartdemo.Session$5.onSuccess(Session.java:355)
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at com.cobboc.eashmartdemo.Session$3.run(Session.java:238)
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
04-11 16:31:31.230: E/AndroidRuntime(9206):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried restoring the last known working copy too. Could it be an issue with my machine?

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964392/im-getting-a-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver/13964418#13964418)

Comment: Have you added the library to Build Path?

Comment: @AndyRes: Do not manually modify the build path. Put the JAR in `libs/`. In fact, manually modifying the build path is precisely what causes this sort of error, as the JAR's contents are available at compile time, but not at runtime.

Comment: I have included the library as a reference. Its also added to the eclipse as a library project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was using new relic to build the app, and when I used eclipse to build it, the libraries failed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the library is in the app libs directory

Look in eclipse - make sure you have a libs directory and that the library is in it

Comment: I have included the library as a reference. Its also added to the eclipse as a library project.