# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

Please this will be not DUPLICATE question

Don't know but I have already put .jar in libs folder and also done following process

[image]

And also

[image]

I have checked this [I'm getting a java.lang.classnotfoundexception: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964392/im-getting-a-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)

I have done several projects but in first time I am getting with this dropbox sample Project

Lotcat is

```
10-14 13:01:00.580: W/dalvikvm(2902): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x430d5140)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902): Process: com.dropbox.sample.hellodropbox, PID: 2902
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAccountManager
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at com.dropbox.sample.hellodropbox.HelloDropboxActivity.onCreate(HelloDropboxActivity.java:44)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5403)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
10-14 13:01:00.580: E/AndroidRuntime(2902):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Even there is a class in Refrenced Libraries

[image]

Please just try with this

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/downloads/sdks/datastore/android/dropbox-android-sync-sdk-3.1.1.zip SDK if you are also getting this kind of error or not
?

Comment: in order and export tab move gen before src and clean and build

Comment: @d.i.v.a tried, but still not working

Comment: is ur jar in ur lib folder?

Comment: ya there is dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar which is in my projects libs directory

Comment: can u https://www.dropbox.com/developers/downloads/sdks/datastore/android/dropbox-android-sync-sdk-3.1.1.zip use this, it hardly takes 5 mins, in that there is jar and example

Comment: its a build issue i guess build the project manually

Comment: NO no I have done with Build Automatically

Comment: thats what m saying to build manually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63013/discussion-between-siddhpura-amit-and-d-i-v-a).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. 
The dropbox-sync-sdk-android.jar was existed on the class-path, but the classes were not included to resulting apk during build process. 
Later I noticed multiple errors in Android build console:

```
 [dx] bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
```

Looks like Dropbox API is compiled against JDK 1.7 and you will have troubles when trying to build APK with this jar using JDK 1.6

I fixed this issue by updating Compiler compliance level:

```
Project->Properties->Java Compiler->Compiler compliance level->1.7
```

Also make sure that your Android SDK Build-tools are v19 or later:

```
Android SDK Manager->Android SDK Build-tools->check v21.0.2->uncheck v17(my case)
```

Comment: Thanks you @kord I have not tested yet but it may be solution :)

Comment: Please consider marking my answer as a correct answer.