# How to convert .jar 1.7 to .jar 1.6

Tags: java, jar, java-6

I've updated Dropbox API framework from 2.0.1 to current 3.1.2 in my android app. While packing my app i'm getting multiple errors like:

> [INFO] trouble processing: [INFO] bad class file magic (cafebabe) or
>   version (0033.0000) [INFO] ...while parsing
>   com/dropbox/sync/android/DbxStringValue.class [INFO] ...while
>   processing com/dropbox/sync/android/DbxStringValue.class [INFO]

It [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355284/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-dropbox-sync-android-dbxaccountmanager) that files are compiled by jdk 1.7 but i'm still using jdk 1.6 and i would not like to update to jdk 1.7 (to avoid new bugs and incompatibilities).

How to convert .jar 1.7 to .jar 1.6?

Comment: Do you have the source?

Comment: No, otherwise i'd just recompiled the sources with my jdk

Comment: `i would not like to update to jdk 1.7 (to avoid new bugs and incompatibilities).`
which incompatiblities are you talking about , I don't think  upgrading to  jdk1.7 will harm you in anyway

Comment: IDEs, proguard and so on

Comment: You recompile everything using a javac targeted to 1.6.

Comment: i'd prefer to recompile **1** library from 1.7 to 1.6 instead of recompile **everything** from 1.6 to 1.7 as i really don't need possible issues

Comment: (In some cases you might get away with just changing the version ID in the .class files, but that would be pretty iffy for a relatively large number of files.)

Comment: If you upgrade there is no need to recompile classes targeted to 1.6.  Java class files are always upward-compatible.

Answer (score 2):

If the jar already contains classes compiled with and targeting Java 7.0, chances are that the classes use features only available in Java 7.0 in which case you won't be able to convert it (unless you relace the codes using Java 7.0 only features codes).

If you're lucky and the classes were just compiled and targeted with Java 7.0 **but** they don't actually use any new features introduced in Java 7.0, you can use a Java decompiler to acquire Java source files from your jar, recompile it with Java 6.0, repack and you're done.

For decompiling `.class` files to `.java` files you can use the [**JD Project**](http://jd.benow.ca/) or goole any other alternatives.

A few more options:

[AndroChef Java Decompiler](http://www.androiddecompiler.com/)

[dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/)

**But best and easiest would be to just upgrade to Java 7.0.** You'll gain much more than you lose (*if* you even lose anything).

Comment: i'm afraid decompiling will produce inefficient java code (loops and so on) and decreases performance. i'm using dex2jar to decompile dex to jar. in my case .jar files are ignored while packing dex so 1.7 classes are just absent in dex

Comment: @4ntoine "decompiling will produce inefficient java code" Luckily for us, the javac does not do any optimizations or code transformations whatsoever. The bytecode is a fairly good representation of the original source code. Therefore, there's no need to be afraid of such things. If the Dropbox jar is not obfuscated, the generated code should also be fairly readable.

Comment: ok, that sounds good. Which tool can decompile jar in batch mode (to have all the source files for jar) ?